# Kubernetes GCP Error response from daemon: No command specified: CreateContainerError

Tags: docker, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I am trying to push my container up to GCP Kubernetes in my cluster. My pod runs locally but it doesn't want to run on GCP. It comes back with this error `Error response from daemon: No command specified: CreateContainerError`

It worked if I run it locally in docker but once I push it up to the container registry on gcp and apply the deployment yaml using `kubectl apply -f` in my namespace it never brings it up and just keeps saying 
`gce-exporting-fsab83222-85sc4   0/1  CreateContainerError  0   5m6s`

I can't get any logs out of it either:
`Error from server (BadRequest): container "gce" in pod "gce-exporting-fsab83222-85sc4" is waiting to start: CreateContainerError`

Heres my files below:

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM alpine:3.8

WORKDIR /build

COPY test.py /build
RUN chmod 755 /build/test.py

CMD ["python --version"]
CMD ["python", "test.py"]
```

*Python Script:*

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import time 

def your_function():
    print("Hello, World")

while True:
    your_function()
    time.sleep(10) #make function to sleep for 10 seconds
```

**yaml file:**

```
apiVersion: apps/v1 
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: gce-exporting
  namespace: "monitoring"
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: gce
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: gce
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: gce
        image: us.gcr.io/lab-manager/lab/gce-exporting:latest
```

I have tried using CMD and Entrypoint at the end to make sure the pod is running but no luck.

This is the output of the describe pod

```
Events:
  Type     Reason     Age               From                                             Message
  ----     ------     ----              ----                                             -------
  Normal   Scheduled  60s               default-scheduler                                Successfully assigned monitoring/gce-exporting-fsab83222-85sc4 to gke-dev-lab-standard-8efad9b6-8m66
  Normal   Pulled     5s (x7 over 59s)  kubelet, gke-dev-lab-standard-8efad9b6-8m66  Container image "us.gcr.io/lab-manager/lab/gce-exporting:latest" already present on machine
  Warning  Failed     5s (x7 over 59s)  kubelet, gke-dev-lab-standard-8efad9b6-8m66  Error: Error response from daemon: No command specified
```

Comment: can you please run ```kubectl describe pods <podname> -n monitoring ``` and check if any other error showing there?

Comment: Added to original desc @hoque

Comment: ```CMD ["python --version"]
CMD ["python", "test.py"]```
can youreplace this two line with
```ENTRYPOINT ["python"]
CMD ["test.py"]``` and check?

Comment: Also use ```FROM python:3``` image if you do not install python in Dockerfile.

Comment: @soniccool does the solution provided by user hoque resolved your issues?

Comment: @Dawid Kruk, figured it out. It was a malformed character in my Dockerfile and caused it to crash.

Answer (score 1):

It was a malformed character in my Dockerfile and caused it to crash.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to update your Dockerfile with following:

```
FROM python

WORKDIR /build
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
ENV PYTHONIOENCODING=UTF-8
COPY test.py /build
RUN chmod 755 /build/test.py

CMD ["python", "test.py"]
```

Then build and push the docker image and recreate pod. Hope it helps!